# Nuxt Environment variable with docker (compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js, httprequest

I have a Nuxt plugin which uses a env
"API_URL" which is read via `process.env.API_URL` it works at localhost but not deployed with docker

docker-compose (part)

```yaml
    environment:
      - API_URL=https://xxx.xxx.de/api/api/v1/
      - BASE_URL=https://xxx.xxx.de/
```

deployed container

```bash
echo $API_URL
https://xxx.xxx.de/api/api/v1
```

But it requests `https://xxx.xxx.de/disease/?usedOnly=` instead of `https://xxx.xxx.de/api/api/v1/disease/?usedOnly=`

frontend log

```
> portal@1.0.0 start
> HOST=0.0.0.0 nuxt start

:information_source: Listening on: http://172.10.10.10:3000/

 ERROR  window is not defined

  at Object.errorHandler (pages/index.js:398:5)
  at pages/index.js:649:12
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)


 ERROR  window is not defined

  at Object.errorHandler (pages/index.js:398:5)
  at pages/index.js:655:12
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)


 ERROR  window is not defined

  at Object.errorHandler (pages/index.js:398:5)
  at pages/index.js:409:12
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try this? Maybe it might help?

- API_URL=https://xxx.xxx.de
- BASE_URL=https://xxx.xxx.de

Comment: Yes. I tried it but then the complete website throws a error 500

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.